# Angular material design - creating a responsive fixed-column width grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to create a horizontally-centered variable-margin grid that has fixed column widths, yet the column count is responsive.

```
<md-bottom-sheet class="no-pad">
  <nav id="resource-tray">
    <md-toolbar>
      <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <h3>title</h3>
        <span flex class="flex"></span>
        <md-button aria-label="Close Tray" ng-click="closeTray()" id="resource-tray-close-control">X</md-button>
      </div>
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-content layout-align="center">
      <md-grid-list
          md-cols-xs="1" md-cols-sm="3" md-cols-md="5" md-cols-lg="7" md-cols-gt-lg="11"
          md-colspan="173px"
          md-row-height="158px">
        <md-grid-tile ng-repeat="page in state.pages"
                  ng-click="selectResource($parent.$index+1)"
                  md-colspan-gt-sm="1"
                  md-rowspan-gt-sm="1">
          <resource-tile ng-repeat="resource in page.data" ng-click="selectResource($parent.$index+1)"></resource-tile>
        </md-grid-tile>
      </md-grid-list>
    </md-content>
  </nav>
</md-bottom-sheet>
```

In the above example, I assumed that setting

```
<md-grid-list md-colspan="173px" ...>
```

would fix the column widths, but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying the resize the bottom sheet add `flex="..."` in the `md-bottom-sheet` tag and to align it in the center add `layout-align="..."` to the `md-buttom-sheet` tag. If thats not what you are trying to do please let me know. –

Comment: I'm not trying to resize the bottom sheet. I am trying to make the grid columns fixed widths with fixed gutters/padding.

Comment: Also, if md-grid-list is not the solution, I'm not attached to it. I just want to create a grid that has this responsive column count: md-cols-xs="1" md-cols-sm="3" md-cols-md="5" md-cols-lg="7" md-cols-gt-lg="11", and has fixed column widths and gutters.

Comment: I saw the responsive answer to this question: [Trying to have a grid of card with angular material](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31726180/trying-to-have-a-grid-of-card-with-angular-material) which satisfies all but one of my requirements. I need the grid to be centered.

Comment: http://blog.sodhanalibrary.com/2015/08/tiles-design-with-md-grid-list-of.html#.VvtCHOV974Y Try this site. For centering try adding an empty tile   as offsets in both sides.