# Aligning cards in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am showing cards using `ng-repeat`. The data and all is coming fine but somehow i am struggling to have 3 cards in a row and go to the next row for the other items.

My `ng-repeat` code is as follows:

```
<md-content ng-repeat="agent in agents|filter:search" layout="row">
            <md-card>
                <md-card-title>
                    <md-card-title-text>
                        <span class="md-subhead">{{agent.RCustId}}</span>
                        <span class="md-headline">{{agent.FullName}}</span>
                        <span class="md-subhead">{{agent.ContactNum}}</span>
                    </md-card-title-text>

                </md-card-title>

                <md-card-content>
                    <p>
                        {{agent.address}}
                    </p>
                </md-card-content>

                <md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="end center">
                    <md-button>Collect {{agent.balance_amount}}</md-button>
                </md-card-actions>

            </md-card>
        </md-content>
```

I want the card side by side but these are coming one per each line.

Where is the issue and how to resolve it please.

Comment: have `ng-repeat` or `md-card` element instead of having it on `mg-content`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try surrounding `md-card` with a `<div>` with `layout-wrap` - you can then use `flex=".."` - with number corresponding to number of columns you want in row.

See layout options documentation [here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/options).

```
<div class='md-padding' layout="row" layout-wrap>
       <md-card flex="33" ng-repeat="agent in agents|filter:search">
```

See answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31726180/trying-to-have-a-grid-of-card-with-angular-material) for more detail and examples.

Answer (score 0):

Add the content inside section

```
<section layout="row" layout-sm="column"  layout-wrap>
// your code
</section>
```

Working example http://plnkr.co/edit/hE38nAAJT35UJL71JGoS?p=preview