# angular 2 material grid list with card

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am facing issue in angular 2 material grid list with cards.

I want to display cards inside grid list but it is not responsive

```
Here is the code:

<md-grid-list cols="4">
  <md-grid-tile *ngFor="let card of cards">
    <md-card>
      <img md-card-image src="{{card.image}}">
      <md-card-content>
        {{card.content}}
      </md-card-content>
    </md-card>
  </md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
```

Comment: You forgot `flex`. Please take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31726180/trying-to-have-a-grid-of-card-with-angular-material) as well.

Comment: thanks @flashjpr . i am trying to use [ng2-flax-layout](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-flex-layout) & but still same problem  here is the code -----<div layout="row"  layoutXs="column"> <md-card style="width: 300px;" *ngFor="let video of videos"  ></md-card></div>

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the reputation to comment so i'll write it as an answer - sorry about that.

You have to be careful setting a fixed width when wanting a responsive view. Try removing the width off of your view, and see what happens. Preferably set your width with flex.
Also if you are using material design, they suggest using fxFlex with their design as pr documentation under layout [here](https://github.com/angular/material2) - link to [fxFlex](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout)

Answer (score 1):

Use Following code in the component.ts file

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.event1 = this.event2 = this.event3 = new EventListComponent();
        this.columns =
          (window.innerWidth <= 400) ? 1
            : (window.innerWidth <= 600) ? 2
            : (window.innerWidth <= 800) ? 3 : 4;
      }
      onResize(event) {
        this.columns =
          (window.innerWidth <= 400) ? 1
            : (window.innerWidth <= 600) ? 2
            : (window.innerWidth <= 800) ? 3 : 4;
      }
```

and use "columns" varialble in your HTML file.
like

```
<mat-grid-list
[cols]="columns"

(window:resize)="onResize($event)">
```

Answer (score -1):

Try changing this

```
<md-grid-list cols="4">
```

To

```
<md-grid-list cols="4" rowHeight="500px" gutterSize="10px">
```